# Increment the product view count

Tags: product, reports

Due to reasons relating to cache I need to programmatically increment the product view count on a Magento site. I have a Jquery function that does an ajax call after page load. This then calls a controller action.
I'm not exactly sure what to do in the controller. So far I was thinking of calling the product view count like so:

```
   $productView = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
        ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $id);
```

Then

```
    $view =$productView->getData('views);
    $view++;
```

Then somehow save $view.

Firstly I'm not sure if $productView is populating because I can't var_dump it but I know this call normally works so I assume it is. My big question is on how to then save the recalculated $view variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to take advantage of the model that handles the product view count in the `Mage_Reports` module. The method that handles this is `Mage_Reports_Model_Event_Observer::catalogProductView`. You can try to call that with a simulated parameter. Let's say that `$id` is your product id. Here goes:

```
$product = new Varien_Object();
$product->setId($id);
$event = new Varien_Event();
$event->setProduct($product);
$observer = new Varien_Event_Observer();
$observer->setEvent($event);
$model = Mage::getModel('reports/event_observer');
$model->catalogProductView($observer);
```

If you do this you should disable the event that counts the product views so you won't end up with duplicate count if the cache is not enabled. For this add this line of code inside one of your custom modules in `config.xml` inside the `<frontend>` tag.

```
<catalog_controller_product_view>
    <observers>
        <reports>
            <type>disabled</type>
        </reports>
    </observers>
</catalog_controller_product_view>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, looks like a good solution. I've just implemented it and wondering about one more thing, what database table should I look at for the number of views just to make sure it's working? I assume it's one of these  report_viewed_product_aggregated_daily
Structure report_viewed_product_aggregated_monthly
Structure report_viewed_product_aggregated_yearly
Structure report_viewed_product_index????

Comment: @ThomasRyan the table is `report_viewed_product_index`. You should see a new line in it every time you look at a product

Comment: I would vote it up but don't have enough of a reputation myself to be allowed to do that but I marked it as accepted